# Can't find how to make a programm that prints a specific part of a specific website into a pdf file when used

Tags: html, pdf

So I am trying to make a program that prints a website into a pdf or a txt file and I need help with a bit of the code. Could anyone help me a bit on ways I could do this?

Comment: Well, what's the "bit of the code" that you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

To have your website print out differently from the browser's default style sheet, you will need a print style sheet. It is just like creating a screen style sheet, but with extra rules.

This article here is a great reference to get you started: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

If you still have issues, post your code here so we can help.